# search item by vue+vuex+vuetify

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, vuex, store

Hello I am trying to learn vue independently by building a small project.
I want to search for products displayed on the page.
I use vue,vuex and vuetify.
I would love to get an idea of ​​how to do this.

> [this is link to my project](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-frost-wob77?file=/src/main.js)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [v-autocomplete](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/)

v-autocomplete by default is meant to searchable.

Updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wing-fpvxo?file=/src/components/CategoriesContainer.vue:124-269)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not my question.
I want to produce a search engine on the products displayed by selected category
Implement SearchItem.vue
I would love an idea of ​​how to realize this